# Can communitheme session be installed in xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu, session, 18.04

Wanted to know as I am considering my options upgrading from xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Communitheme session, which comes with the Communitheme snap package, is for Gnome Shell, so no, it won't work in Xubuntu. The Gtk and icon themes can be installed in Xubuntu by using the [Communitheme PPA](https://launchpad.net/~communitheme/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: That's sad, rules out one option. Could you give some source regarding this, or is it that someone tried this out? What other options do I have apart from clean installing normal ubuntu?

Comment: The source... is actually the source code:https://launchpad.net/~communitheme/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/gnome-shell-communitheme_18.04~wip1+201804261001+8d001ef~ubuntu18.04.1.tar.xz If you look in the source, under recipe > session, in the ubuntu-communitheme.desktop file you'll find this: "Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu-communitheme gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=gnome-shell". The session loads Gnome itself...